# Why .net core hosted on Linux prepends a backslash on urls's hostnames?

Tags: .net-core, amazon-linux

In the log of my .net core app I can see that the URLs for all requests are prepended with a backslash. The application is hosted on Amazon Linux 2 using .net core 2.0. Here is how the url is used in the request: `http://www.mvc.meetcorepoint.com/` and here is the url received by .net core `http://\www.mvc.meetcorepoint.com/`. Here is a part of the log that show this for other urls too:

```
dotnet-ids.mvc[22185]: info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
dotnet-ids.mvc[22185]: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://\www.mvc.meetcorepoint.com/
dotnet-ids.mvc[22185]: info:     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
dotnet-ids.mvc[22185]: Executing action method     MvcClient.Controllers.HomeController.Index (MvcClient) with arguments ((null)) -
dotnet-ids.mvc[22185]: info:     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.ViewResultExecutor[1]
dotnet-ids.mvc[22185]: Executing ViewResult, running view at path     /Views/Home/Index.cshtml.
dotnet-ids.mvc[22185]: info:     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
dotnet-ids.mvc[22185]: Executed action     MvcClient.Controllers.HomeController.Index (MvcClient) in 0.5249ms
dotnet-ids.mvc[22185]: info:     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
dotnet-ids.mvc[22185]: Request finished in 0.7982ms 200 text/html;     charset=utf-8
dotnet-ids.mvc[22185]: info:     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
dotnet-ids.mvc[22185]: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET     http://\www.mvc.meetcorepoint.com/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css
dotnet-ids.mvc[22185]: info:     Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[2]
dotnet-ids.mvc[22185]: Sending file. Request path: '/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'. Physical path: '/var/www/dotnet/ids
dotnet-ids.mvc[22185]: info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
dotnet-ids.mvc[22185]: Request finished in 1.6629ms 200 text/css
dotnet-ids.mvc[22185]: info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
dotnet-ids.mvc[22185]: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://\www.mvc.meetcorepoint.com/css/site.css
dotnet-ids.mvc[22185]: info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[2]
dotnet-ids.mvc[22185]: Sending file. Request path: '/css/site.css'. Physical path: '/var/www/dotnet/ids.mvc/wwwroot/css/site.cs
dotnet-ids.mvc[22185]: info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
dotnet-ids.mvc[22185]: Request finished in 0.3626ms 200 text/css
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out this had nothing to do with Linux, nor with .net core itself. The problem was in my nginx configuration which is used as a reverse proxy to the .net core application. When I was coping the proxy nginx configuration from the web, it somehow prepended a backslash on the `Upgrade` and `Host` headers. So instead of having `proxy_set_header Host $host;` I had used `proxy_set_header Host \$host;`